# Python: turtle - (exit)onclick while in infinite loop?

Tags: python, loops, onclick, turtle-graphics

I am learning Python (2.7) and currently turtles is on the list.

Regards the documentation there are exitonclick() and onclick() etc. functions. However, I have some problems utilizing them.

For instance: 
This click event is working, but only after the loop finishes:

```
[...]
for i in range(4):
    trtl.forward(100)
    trtl.left(90)
scrn.exitonclick()
[...]
```

But what I'd like to do are things like this (but are not working):

```
[...]
while not scrn.screenonclick():
    trtl.forward(100)
    trtl.left(91)
[...]
```

or maybe like this:

```
[...]
while True:
    trtl.forward(100)
    trtl.left(91)
    scrn.screenonclick(break)
[...]
```

I think you get the general idea about what concepts I try to experiment with.

Any tips in using these onclick methods or any alternative ways in accomplishing an onclick interrupt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried moving the click handler to the beginning? Here binding to the click will be made before the drawing starts:

```
def say_bye(x, y):
    bye()

scrn.onclick(say_bye)

for i in range(4):
    trtl.forward(100)
    trtl.left(90)
```

Comment: hm, unfortunately it is not an attribute:

"AttributeError: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'screenonclick'"

Comment: Unfortunately, the second idea does not work neither. The program just blocks on exitonclick() until the screen is clicked - which obviously exits the screen before it goes into the loop. ^^

Comment: One more try please :)

Comment: Thx for your persistence. :-) Yes this works! At least in a pragmatic way. The downside seems to be that the Screen instance has to be a global variable, so bye() can be called. :-/

Comment: Wonderful! Could you accept the answer if you are happy with it? Here is how: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Jep, I was just waiting some time to give others this possibility, too . :-)